# Maven adds different dependencies on different machines?

Tags: java, maven, jboss

SOLVED I have a project with maven as its build tool. When I build it on my machine using "mvn –P DEV clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true" command it works fine. But when I send it to my client and he builds it on the test server with the same command there are some additional dependencies that appear from nowhere and brake everything.
[![img][1]][1]
on the left it is clients build. and on the right it is mine. Notice slf4j-simple that just appeared from nowhere after building on the client machine. Could you please explain to me what is going on?
We use Java 7, Jboss 7.1.1, and maven as a build tool. No slf4j-simple is added in maven. There is no slf4j-simple in my project dependencies and it should NOT be there.
Here is my pom.xml

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oracle</id>
            <name>oracle</name>
            <url>http://www.cameliatk.jp/maven2/repository/thirdparty/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <poi.version>3.15</poi.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.19.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.search>4.4.1.Final</hibernate.search>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.1.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <maven.antrun.plugin.version>1.8</maven.antrun.plugin.version>
        <log4j.version>2.12.1</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.30</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--//Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.search}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Spring Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Apache POI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Apache Velocity-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Apache Lucene-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Apache Solr-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Apache Commons-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <!--//Jackson-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--//-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--         Binding for Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--         Log4j API and Core implementation required for binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.v201112011016</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- direct JDBC access to ILS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
            <version>8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>stax</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>pet-web-DEV</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.antrun.plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>validate</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <delete file="WebContent/WEB-INF/application-security.xml"/>

                                        <copy file="configs/dev/application-security.xml"
                                              tofile="WebContent/WEB-INF/application-security.xml"/>
                                        <!--copy resources to src/resources-->
                                        <delete file="src/main/resources/application.properties"/>

                                        <copy file="configs/dev/application.properties"
                                              tofile="src/main/resources/application.properties"/>
                                        <!--copy resources to src/resources/META-INF-->
                                        <delete file="src/main/resources/META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml"/>

                                        <copy file="configs/dev/jpa-persistence.xml"
                                              tofile="src/main/resources/META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml"/>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                            <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>


    </profiles>
</project>
```

I found the reason for this!!

Thank you all for your help. The reason was that client when copying new deployment doesn't completely erase old files. And this simple-slf4j is left from an old build.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q79FJ.png

Comment: Please post your pom.xml, or build.gradle, or whatever you are using to define the package. Or at least the portion that contains slf4j-simple.

Comment: There is no slf4j-simple in my project dependencies and it should NOT be there.

Comment: First thing to do would be to both build a dependency tree and compare the output `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree` It's presumably a transitive dependency of something

Comment: Okay, fine, please post the pom.xml or build.gradle or whatever you are using to define the maven packages. @Michael transitive dependency wouldn't explain differences by host though.

Comment: @Chi-YoungJeffreyLii Maven can have profiles which are activated on platform (win, mac, unix) so it is perfectly *possible* for different platforms to build *completely* differently.It's usually not likely, but still

Comment: I edited my answer and added pom.xml

Comment: @Chi-YoungJeffreyLii

Comment: You don't need to add two comments, I was going over your pom.xml. 1) it's incomplete. 

2) It looks your log4j's is calling a separate version of slf4j as a dependency. Either force it to call the same version of slf4j or change the version # so it calls the same version of slf4j

Comment: But how these different versions of the logging framework can cause different build dependencies? I added full pom.xml just removed the first 4 lines with the name of the artifact. I will change those versions but I don`t think it is the reason.

Comment: Dependency resolution in maven is explained here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution and http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html @Michael You are correct.

Comment: Thank you for those links. Why when I build on my machine those transitive dependencies are not added? I thought that maven tool is a platform independent

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this!!

Thank you all for your help. The reason was that client when copying new deployment doesn't completely erase old files. And this simple-slf4j is left from an old build.

Comment: You said he ran with `mvn –P DEV clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`. Clean should remove all old artifacts, so your question was misleading.

Comment: He actually does run mvn –P DEV clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true but after this he copied over the war to the server. This is where old files were left on the server